# I am confused the fields 'available' and 'shared' after keying in command of 'free -h'

Tags: linux, free

As my title announced, I looked up their meanings and get that the field 'shared' has been dropped and my available memory = free + buffer/cache. Maybe owing to the old version, I haven't found the explanation of field 'available', all articles I have found do not display field of 'available' after entering 'free -h'. What's more, I want to know more about the field 'shared' because I found that the value of 'shared' changed after I modified the sga of the oracle instance. Next two texts display this change(first is before that I modified sga, and the second is after).

```
    [oracle@VM-0-6-centos ~]$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.7G        1.3G        120M        2.0G        2.3G        177M
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

---

```
    oracle@VM-0-6-centos ~]$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.7G        1.3G        130M        1.5G        2.3G        683M
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

Thank you.

Comment: See [man 1 free](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/free.1.html)

Comment: You have a good question, but you have posted to the wrong StackEachange site. I’m voting to close this question because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).